# Python - Function that sums list's with error

Tags: python, list, function, python-3.x

```
def somalist (lista):
    listasoma = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    for i in lista:
        for g in i:
            if i.index(g) != 0 and i.index(g) != 1 and i.index(g) != 2 and i.index(g) != 3:
                listasoma[i.index(g)] += g
            else:
                listasoma[i.index(g)] = g
            print(listasoma)
    return(listasoma)
```

`x = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]]
print(somalist(x))`

is that the function, it works doing the sum of each sublist but it preserves the the index [0], [1], [2] and [3] and sum the anothers. In this example I will use the list `x`, in this list the function works correctly. The exit of the program is:

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 32, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 22]`

is what I've said it preserves the members [0],[1],[2],[3] and sum the other indices of each sublist.

But when we use some number more than once, it fails.

using:`X = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],[1,2,3,4,**6**,6,7,8,9,10,11],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]]`

> the 6 (index 4) in second sublist was writen twice (the another at the index 5 at the same sublist)

the exit was :`[1, 2, 3, 4, **22**, 12, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33]`

It's wrong!

The correct exit should be: `[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 16, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33]`

Can someone tell me where my code is wrong?

Comment: Please choose a better title

Comment: i'm sorry, it was my first topic here in stackoverflow

Comment: As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list#common-sequence-operations), `index()` only finds the first occurrence.

Comment: for g in i: here you should use enumerate...

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 i've understand but how can i solve this problem? do you know another function that substiitutes `index()`?

@EricLevieil how can i do that?, i couldn't uderstand you

Comment: I tried your code and instead of the `[1, 2, 3, 4, 32, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 22]` you got, I got `[1, 2, 3, 4, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33]` as I expected. How are you getting that result?

Comment: i've change the index 4 from 5 to 6, and because of this number written twice i'm the same sublist the function fails

Comment: No, I mean the output you state for the working one with no repeats appears incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend ditching the `index()` approach entirely.

```
def somalist (lista):
    return lista[0][:4] + [sum(item) for item in list(zip(*lista))[4:]]
```

This works on `list`s with repeated elements.

```
                                            v
>>> x = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]]
>>> X = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],[1,2,3,4,6,6,7,8,9,10,11],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]]
>>> print(somalist(x))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33]
>>> print(somalist(X))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 16, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33]
             ^^
```